# How to use Moveit2 in ROS2 Humble with my own custom URDF?

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, urdf, moveit

I am trying to use Moveit2 with ROS2 Humble. I followed the documentation provided and I was able to recreate the panda robot configurations from the MoveIt Setup Assistant and launching the generated demo.launch.py launch file successfully which proves that my installation is not the problem.
I am writing a URDF file using basic shapes like boxes and cylinders, also I am specifying the visuals, collision and inertial params of the links as well as the limits on the joints and I am being able to see the robot model in RVIZ and control the joints using joint_state_publisher_gui.

My problem is when using MoveIt with this URDF.
When applying the same logic in my workspace with my custom URDF rather than the panda URDF and after making the necessary changes to the other files, I am able to use MoveIt Setup Assistant with my URDF (Although the robot model is not appearing on the right hand side of the MSA) and configure my robot. After building the workspace and launching the generated demo.launch.py launch file, RVIZ is opening but the model cannot be loaded.

[GitHub Repository of the Workspace](https://github.com/Fadi-Eid/arm_ws)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Fadi EID. What do you mean when you say `RVIZ is opening but the model cannot be loaded.` Are you getting an error or warning in RVIZ? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Hello Chuck, thank you for the reply. The problem was something related to velocity limits being integers rather than double even though I've set the values to 10.0. The fix consisted of editing those values with 10.00001 instead and that did the work. I can now successfully launch the launch file demo.launch.py generated by MSA and seing the robot. A new problem appeared when the robot end with the sphere on the end effector, the movement seems constrained and also after a while RVIZ freezes with error: "Goal request rejected. Can't accept new action goals. Controller is not running"